# Android Dagger 2 compile errors

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm getting compile errors when attempting to create a second Dagger 2 Component that injects something into the same classes as the first.  Is that not allowed?  I haven't found any documentation that says it isn't.

Module 1:

```
@Module
public class NavModule {

    Context context;

    public NavModule(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides @Named("nav")
    public List<NAV_ACTIONS> provideNavActions() {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Component 1:

```
@Component(modules = {NavModule.class})
public interface NavComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(AbstractHomeFragment fragment);
}
```

Module 2:

```
@Module
public class OtherModule {

    Context context;

    public OtherModule(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    public Object provideSomething(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

At this point everything still compiles fine.  When I add Component 2, it breaks:

```
@Component(modules = {OtherModule.class})
public interface OtherComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(AbstractHomeFragment fragment);
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
Error:(14, 10) error: @javax.inject.Named("nav") java.util.List<NAV_ACTIONS> cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
@javax.inject.Named("nav") java.util.List<NAV_ACTIONS> is injected at
com.company.common.MainActivity.navActions
com.company.common.MainActivity is injected at
com.company.common.dependency.OtherComponent.inject(activity)

Error:(15, 10) error: @javax.inject.Named("home") java.util.List<com.company.common.NAV_ACTIONS> cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
@javax.inject.Named("home") java.util.List<com.company.common.NAV_ACTIONS> is injected at
com.company.common.views.AbstractHomeFragment.homeActions
com.company.common.views.AbstractHomeFragment is injected at
com.company.common.dependency.OtherComponent.inject(fragment)

E:\Development\Repositories\PropertyForce\PropertyForce_Android\app\src\main\java\com\company\common\MainActivity.java
Error:(50, 47) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNavComponent
Error:(50, 47) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNavComponent

E:\Development\Repositories\PropertyForce\PropertyForce_Android\app\src\main\java\com\company\common\views\AbstractHomeFragment.java
Error:(29, 47) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNavComponent
Error:(29, 47) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNavComponent
```

Here's the Dagger related stuff from `MainActivity`.  The editor shows no errors.

```
import com.company.common.dependency.DaggerNavComponent;
import com.company.common.dependency.NavComponent;
import com.company.common.dependency.NavModule;
// ...
@Inject @Named("nav") List<NAV_ACTIONS> navActions;
// ...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        NavComponent navComponent = DaggerNavComponent.builder().navModule(new NavModule(this)).build();
        navComponent.inject(this);
// ...
```

`AbstractHomeFragment` is doing very similar things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add **NavModule** and **OtherModule** together in the injected modules list in single **component** which you have declared in your **Application**:

```
@Component(modules = {OtherModule.class, NavModule.class})
public interface OtherComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(AbstractHomeFragment fragment);
}
```

Edit -- You can have multiple components but you would need to Initialise them in your **Application.class** file. I suggested here to use in single as you were injecting 2 different modules in same classes.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I see!  So to make sure I understand correctly, you're only ever supposed to have one `Component` in the application?  And by "Application" you mean the app, and not the `android.os.Application` subclass, right?

Comment: Another question - when creating a `Component` object, I pass in a `Module`.  So to get things injected from two different modules, do I need to create two `Component` instances, one for each `Module`?

Comment: I have edited the ans. And you don't need to call the builder in the class file. You do that in the Application file. You only need to use @Inject. You can check my demo app to understand : https://github.com/code-crusher/android-demos/tree/master/Dagger2

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out.